# Извлечь текст заключенный в кавычках

Tags: php, opencart

Использую регулярное выражение:

```
preg_match_all('#"([а-я]{0,})"#u', $string, $product_name);
var_dump($product_name);
```

Если так:

```
$string = 'Сегодня ранним "утром" произошло некоторое событие.';
```

то все ок.

Но мне нужно получить $result['name']:

```
$string = $result['name'];
```

А так почему-то не работает. Возвращает пустой массив. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем загвоздка?

Answer (score 0):

Можно достать через [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php)

```
$result['name'] = 'Сегодня ранним "утром" произошло некоторое событие.';
preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/', $result['name'], $p);
print_r($p[1]);
```

[пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/710fbceb2af58ffb6f11e5d62d2ee2776c553715)

Comment: Если так: `$string = 'Сегодня ранним "утром" произошло некоторое событие.';`, то работает. Проблема если я вывожу $result['name']. Возвращает пустой массив. Хотя в $result['name'] содержится этот же текст.

Comment: Достаёт нормально, возможно проблема не в этом?

Comment: Я же и не говорю что проблема в этом, просто хочу понять в чем именно проблема.

Comment: в каком файле вы это делаете и какая версия опенкарта?

Comment: /catalog/controller/product/category.php ocStore 2.3.0.2

Comment: Ну а $result что должна содержать(какие данные, от куда) и где формируется?

Comment: Стандартный массив с товарами: `$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);
foreach ($results as $result) {`

Comment: ок. а в каком месте вы делаете $string = $result['name'];?

Comment: Перед `$data['products'][] = array(` https://pastenow.ru/55KU7

Comment: $result['name'] не пустой перед присваиванием?

Comment: Нет, там названия товаров.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать html_entity_decode()

```
$string = html_entity_decode($result['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/', $string, $product_name);
```

Comment: То есть, там не просто название товаров, а аж-но верстка с названием? Не рекомендую так делать.

Comment: Если смотреть через var_dump или print_r, то выводится просто текст, без html, но почему-то без html_entity_decode работать не хочет. Это опенкарт.

Comment: Ну это потому, что вы смотрите из браузера, а если открыть исходный код, увидите, что там `html` присутствует. `CTRL+U` или правой кнопкой мыши и Исходный код страницы. Но `html_entity_decode`, я думаю вам тогда лучше заменить на `strip_tags`.

Comment: Блин, точно! как я мог это не увидеть) Но `strip_tags` не срабатывает, пробовал.

Comment: Не может быть, чтобы он не срабатывал, видимо, что-то не так делаете.

Comment: strip_tags удаляет html теги, а там только кавычки в HTML. Но кавычки то мне нужны, как без них я определю какую часть текста мне вырезать?

Comment: Там используется `&quot;` или `&#34;` ? Я так не думаю. А вообще, нужно видеть, что там в исходном  `html` страницы. А то гадать на кофейной гуще не хочется. Но есть подозрения, что вы просто преобразуете `html сущности`.

Comment: Там `&#34;` вместо кавычек.

Comment: А чем мешает тогда сделать поиск именно по `&#34;`? `/&#34;(.+?)&#34;/` ? Чтобы не юзать `html_entity_decode`, если требуется лишь в кавычках, если нет, то тогда да, без `html_entity_decode` никак. Но тут еще факт в том, что после преобразования, у вас будет `html`, следовательно - если попадется аттрибут, все рухнит. Я все-же думаю, вам следует найти более верный подход.